# Why are Ruby hashes called hashes, and not maps, dicts, tables or associatve arrays?

Tags: ruby, language-design

In Ruby, there is a built-in class called [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html). According to [the docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html):

> A Hash is a dictionary-like collection of unique keys and their values. Also called associative arrays, they are similar to Arrays, but where an Array uses integers as its index, a Hash allows you to use any object type.
>
> ...
>
> A Hash can be easily created by using its implicit form:
>
> ```
> grades = { "Jane Doe" => 10, "Jim Doe" => 6 }
> ```

So basically, they're [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). If that's the case, then why are they called hashes? In Computer Science, isn't the term "hash" usually used to refer to a number or hexadecimal string of some kind generated by running some data through a [hash function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)? In fact, Ruby objects even have a method called [`hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Object.html#method-i-hash) which "generates a Fixnum hash value for this object".

I'm aware that [`Hash`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Hash.html) in Ruby is implemented as a [hash table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), but given what I've said above that doesn't seem like enough justification for using the name `Hash` over something like `Table` or `Map`, especially given that Ruby doesn't seem to have any other built-in implementations of [associative arrays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_array). Why was this name chosen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ruby takes a large amount of inspiration from Perl, and Perl calls this a hash.

**UPDATE:**

Confirmed by Yukihiro Matsumoto, creator of Ruby: https://twitter.com/yukihiro_matz/status/547516495249428480

Comment: Hmm, so perhaps for historical reasons then. This answer begs the question though: why did Perl choose the term "hash" over "map", "dict", "table", or "associative array"?

Comment: As good of an answer as you're probably going to get. But then it begs the question... why does Perl call it a hash?

Comment: I can't find an authoritative source, but the consensus seems to be that associative arrays in Perl ended up mainly being called hashes because they use hashing internally and "hash" is a significantly shorter and easier to say/write than "associative array".

Comment: @AndrewMedico Could you post whatever sources you did find if you still remember them?

Comment: @Ajedi32, as this is the best answer you're likely to get, would you please mark it as the answer?

Comment: I'll see if I can dig it up again.

Comment: @OneHoopyFrood Eh, sure, why not? I still consider this to be an incomplete answer, but like you said this is probably the best I'm going to get.